# How yo bulk delete a custom post type of WordPress using just single line SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Last time i required to delete more than a million queries from MySQL data base with help of a single line code. I literally cant remember the exact query.
As an example currently i require it to delete a post type in my site that is "episodes".
    post_type=episodes

Can any one write me a single line query for this?

Comment: DELETE FROM yourtablename WHERE post_type Like 'episodes'

Comment: First thing First.  Backup your db before you do this.